# how to fill Array Within the Start Date and End Date in android

Tags: android

Suppose I want Array Of Dates i want Dates between

Start Date- 26/9/2012
End Date-3/10/2012

diffinDays=7;
What i am doing is

```
    for(int i=0;i<diffInDays;i++){

        DateArray[i]=StartDate.toString();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
            c.setTime(sdf.parse(StartDate));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        // number of days to add

        StartDate= sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
        }
```

It Addes me Date but when the Date is 30/09/2012 how can i add Month?

Answer (score 1):

No need to add month when the date is `30/09/2012`. the calendar will automatically get the days how many you want. just mange the `diffinDays` variable in for loop and you will see the array of dates in `DateArray`. Just look at this code

```
 String StartDate= "30/09/2012",EndDate="7/10/2012";

    for(int i=0;i<diffinDays;i++){

        DateArray[i]=StartDate.toString();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
        Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
            c.setTime(sdf.parse(StartDate));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        // number of days to add

        StartDate= sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
        System.out.println(DateArray[i]);
        }
```

Comment: can you please tell how to keep doing the same for getting every six month date between 2 dates

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

This is easier in Joda-Time.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "d/M/yyyy" );
LocalDate start = formatter.parseLocalDate( "26/9/2012" );
// loop
LocalDate localDate = start.plusDays( i );
```